# Haskell - Checking if pairs of coordinates form connected graph

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell at the moment and am working on a little project on my own. The problem I'm trying to solve is that I am trying to create a function that takes a list of coordinate paths and determines whether they form a connected graph or not. It is defined as follows:

```
isConnected :: [((Integer, Integer), (Integer, Integer))] -> Bool
```

Lists of coordinates could be in the following format, for example:

```
[((0,0),(0,3)), ((0,2),(2,2)), ((2,1),(4,1)),
 ((4,0),(4,2)), ((4,2),(5,2)), ((2,1),(2,5)),
 ((1,5),(4,5))]
```

The criteria for determining whether or not two paths are connected is that there must be at least **one point** which is on both of the paths.

The whole graph is connected if **all the paths** in the list of coordinates are connected - so if this was the case, isConnected should return **true.** Otherwise, return **false.** The list of coordinates above would form a connected graph for example, but this wouldn't:

```
[((0,0),(0,3)), ((0,2),(2,2)), ((2,1),(4,1)),
 ((4,0),(4,2)), ((4,2),(5,2)), ((2,1),(2,5)),
 ((4,5),(5,5))]
```

At the moment, I'm not totally sure how to go about this particular problem; I know that I have to determine whether or not every path overlaps throughout the list but I don't know how I'd implement this in Haskell as I'm still relatively new to the language. Any help would be appreciated on this problem, as I'm finding it very difficult to solve myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your choice of data type (a list of tuples of tuples) is kind of making my head spin, so I'd suggest introducing at least a `Segment` data type to represent a line between two points (what you're calling a "path", I think).  A type alias for `Point` might be helpful, too:

```
type Point = (Integer, Integer)
data Segment = Segment Point Point deriving (Show)
```

**Hint #1:**  With that out of the way, you may find it easiest to calculate the set of connected components from the list of segments.  Then, your whole graph is connected if the number of components is equal to one (or, if an empty graph should be connected, then if the number of components is less than or equal to one):

```
isConnected :: [Segment] -> Bool
isConnected ps = length (components ps) <= 1

components :: [Segment] -> [[Segment]]
components = ...
```

**Hint #2:** The *reason* you might want to calculate the set of connected components is that this is relatively easy to express recursively:

```
components :: [Segment] -> [[Segment]]
components (p:ps) = ... some expression involving `components ps` ...
```

**Hint #3:** (minor spoilers)  If we have a list of segments `(p:ps)`, and we've already calculated the connected components of `ps` as `components ps`, then the connected components of the larger list `(p:ps)` can be determined as follows:

Search through `components ps` to find any components that are connected to `p` (i.e., that have a segment within that component that intersects `p`).  Observe that:

- If you find exactly one such component, then `p` should be added to that component.
- If you find two or more such components, then `p` connects them together, and they should all be combined into a single component with `p` added.
- If there are no such components, then `p` is in a component all by itself, and it should be added as an additional component.

All three cases above can be simplified into one step:  Partition the `components ps` list into the components that are connected to `p` and the ones that aren't, merge the former together and add `p` to make a single component, and copy the latter components as-is.

**Hint #4:** (major spoilers)  The code to implement Hint #3 is:

```
components :: [Segment] -> [[Segment]]
components (p:ps) = (p : concat qs) : rs
  where (qs, rs) = partition (p `intersectsComponent`) (components ps)
components [] = []

-- Does first segment intersect anything in the given component?
intersectsComponent :: Segment -> [Segment] -> Bool
intersectsComponent = ...
```

**COMPLETE SPOILERS**

.

.

.

The function `intersectsComponent` just checks if a given segment intersects any segment in the given component:

```
intersectsComponent :: Segment -> [Segment] -> Bool
intersectsComponent p ps = any (intersects p) ps
```

and the function `intersects` checks if two segments intersect.  This is a rather tedious algorithm to get right, so I just translated it from the Python version [here](https://algorithmtutor.com/Computational-Geometry/Check-if-two-line-segment-intersect/).

```
intersects :: Segment -> Segment -> Bool
intersects (Segment p1 p2) (Segment p3 p4)
  = (d1 > 0 && d2 < 0 || d1 < 0 && d2 > 0) && (d3 > 0 && d4 < 0 || d3 < 0 && d4 > 0)
  || d1 == 0 && on_segment p3 p4 p1
  || d2 == 0 && on_segment p3 p4 p2
  || d3 == 0 && on_segment p1 p2 p3
  || d4 == 0 && on_segment p1 p2 p4

  where d1 = direction p3 p4 p1
        d2 = direction p3 p4 p2
        d3 = direction p1 p2 p3
        d4 = direction p1 p2 p4

        direction q1 q2 q3 = cross_product (pdiff q3 q1) (pdiff q2 q1)
        pdiff (x,y) (x',y') = (x-x',y-y')
        cross_product (x,y) (x',y') = x*y'-x'*y

        on_segment (q1x,q1y) (q2x,q2y) (qx,qy)
          =  min q1x q2x <= qx
          && qx <= max q1x q2x
          && min q1y q2y <= qy
          && qy <= max q1y q2y
```

*Full code with your examples as test cases:*

```
import Data.List

type Point = (Integer, Integer)
data Segment = Segment Point Point deriving (Show)

isConnected :: [Segment] -> Bool
isConnected ps = length (components ps) <= 1

components :: [Segment] -> [[Segment]]
components (p:ps) = (p : concat qs) : rs
  where (qs, rs) = partition (p `intersectsComponent`) (components ps)
components [] = []

intersectsComponent :: Segment -> [Segment] -> Bool
intersectsComponent p ps = any (intersects p) ps

intersects :: Segment -> Segment -> Bool
intersects (Segment p1 p2) (Segment p3 p4)
  = (d1 > 0 && d2 < 0 || d1 < 0 && d2 > 0) && (d3 > 0 && d4 < 0 || d3 < 0 && d4 > 0)
  || d1 == 0 && on_segment p3 p4 p1
  || d2 == 0 && on_segment p3 p4 p2
  || d3 == 0 && on_segment p1 p2 p3
  || d4 == 0 && on_segment p1 p2 p4

  where d1 = direction p3 p4 p1
        d2 = direction p3 p4 p2
        d3 = direction p1 p2 p3
        d4 = direction p1 p2 p4

        direction q1 q2 q3 = cross_product (pdiff q3 q1) (pdiff q2 q1)
        pdiff (x,y) (x',y') = (x-x',y-y')
        cross_product (x,y) (x',y') = x*y'-x'*y

        on_segment (q1x,q1y) (q2x,q2y) (qx,qy)
          =  min q1x q2x <= qx
          && qx <= max q1x q2x
          && min q1y q2y <= qy
          && qy <= max q1y q2y

ex1 = [Segment (0,0) (0,3), Segment (0,2) (2,2), Segment (2,1) (4,1),
       Segment (4,0) (4,2), Segment (4,2) (5,2), Segment (2,1) (2,5),
       Segment (1,5) (4,5)]

ex2 = [Segment (0,0) (0,3), Segment (0,2) (2,2), Segment (2,1) (4,1),
       Segment (4,0) (4,2), Segment (4,2) (5,2), Segment (2,1) (2,5),
       Segment (4,5) (5,5)]

main = do
  print $ isConnected ex1
  print $ isConnected ex2
```